# Importing textured model into Photoshop

Tags: export, file-format

I'm very new to Blender and have entered into the 3D world to mix it with my photography. I have made the following glowing torus and would like to import it as it looks on Blender into Photoshop.

Any clues on how to do it? Right now, whenever I click on 'New 3D Layer from File' in Photoshop, I'm getting just the Polygons and that is not what I want.

Also, is there a way to make the torus smoother? Zooming in, I can see that the edges look more like tangents rather than a smooth curve and I would like to eliminate that.

This is probably a basic question but since I'm still getting the grips with the fundamentals of 3D, doing an internet search while lacking the technical jargon has been difficult. :(

[image]
How I'd like my render to be imported in Photoshop (I'm importing an .obj file)

[image]
What I'm getting right now on Photoshop (just polygons)

Comment: Do you want just a picture of the 3d render, or the 3d object itself? Also, to make the torus smoother, try adding a subdivision surface modifier in the modifiers tab, or using the `Shade Smooth` option.

Comment: It seems like Photoshop is not receiving the material settings from blender. If I recall correctly, the .obj format does not store material data. Is there a different format you can use? Also - it looks like you've got volumetric effects in the blender screen shot, I doubt you will be able to get photoshop to render those.

Comment: Thank you person132 and GiantCowFilms for the reply! I want the fully-rendered 3D object itself, not just an image. Is it possible? In the meantime, I'll look further into your answers on Google. You've given me a good direction. :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541